# "failed to load source for dependency `obce`"

Tags: ink, substrate-contracts-node

I want to build locally [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) to be able develop ink smart contracts and after cloning repository I have executed `cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git` and got this error:

```
error: failed to compile `contracts-node v0.23.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git#87a3d76c)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installEfgqLE`

Caused by:
  failed to get `obce` as a dependency of package `pallet-assets-chain-extension v0.1.1 (https://github.com/727-Ventures/pallet-assets-chain-extension?branch=polkadot-v0.9.34#1680c99e)`
      ... which satisfies git dependency `pallet-assets-chain-extension` of package `contracts-node-runtime v0.23.0 (/home/tomek/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-contracts-node-cf7c16677784d274/87a3d76/runtime)`
      ... which satisfies path dependency `contracts-node-runtime` of package `contracts-node v0.23.0 (/home/tomek/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-contracts-node-cf7c16677784d274/87a3d76/node)`

Caused by:
  failed to load source for dependency `obce`

Caused by:
  Unable to update https://github.com/727-Ventures/obce?branch=polkadot-v0.9.34

Caused by:
  failed to find branch `polkadot-v0.9.34`

Caused by:
  cannot locate remote-tracking branch 'origin/polkadot-v0.9.34'; class=Reference (4); code=NotFound (-3)
```

I am aware of the fact that I can download and run already released build from Github, but I guess that some people will want to build a node locally. Appreciate any hints.

Comment: did you try to add `--force --locked` while installing?

Comment: After the comment I was trying "cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git --force --locked", got same result (error).

Comment: I just use `cargo install contracts-node --force --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git` command by omitting --locked flag and it works for me. [you can view image in link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17kfil0V9T3jBqHqj0_ZHM7bV6mTsV8sI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for trying, no idea why I got this.

Comment: @TomaszWaszczyk  Could you make it work? I faced the same issue, also saw your issue on the repo link in GitHub.

Comment: @Ganesh11 Are you sure it works? It throws the same error when I do it

Comment: Nope, I still face the issue. I know that on Apple's machines the error does not occur, but on Linux compilation does not work. Probably something bad is with linking libraries, but I do not understand details. Amount of magic is too much for me.

Comment: @TomaszWaszczyk Sure thanks, if you do get something, post it as a solution.

Comment: this was due to a missing branch in the obce repo, I fixed it pls lmk if the issue still persists

Comment: It works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was due to a missing branch in the `obce` repository.

Those who has the issue, try one more time, should work now.